# Canvas element active by default even though it's set to inactive in the script

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

The pause menu is getting shown by default when I click the play button, even though the `GameIsPaused` boolean is set to false. I don't know if it's the fault of how I referenced it in the engine itself or how the script is written.

Here's how I referenced it in Unity:

[image: Screenshot of canvas inspector]

And here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (!GameIsPaused)
            {
                Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                Resume();
            }
        }
    }
    

    public void Resume()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        GameIsPaused = false;
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
    void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        GameIsPaused = true;
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }
    public void LoadMenu()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading Game...");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }
    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Quitting Game...");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code that toggles the pause menu active state runs only when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed.

Did you mean to also run similar code in `Start()` to set the initial state of the menu when this script loads, something like...

```
void Start() {
    if (GameIsPaused)
    {
        Pause();
    }
    else
    {
        Resume();
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Yeah, I meant to set it to inactive by default

Comment: You can also just untick the Pause menu object's "Active" checkbox in the top-left of the Inspector before running/building the game, if you prefer to do it without a start-up script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just disabling the PauseMenu just like this

[image]